# Foreach Faulty Output.Show the same results

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

there is no problem using one foreach.But it's a problem when you use it nested.I have tried many methods but I can not get the result I want.

```
$first[] = array($firstforeach);
$second[] = array($secondforeach);
```

I create a new two array and take it out.Then I use them in new foreach.

```
foreach ($first as $first1) {
    foreach ($second as $second1=>$second2) {   
        echo "a: ".$second1." b: ".$first1[0]." c: ".$second2[0]."</br>";
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following output.

```
a: 0 b: apple   c: 100
a: 1 b: pear    c: 100
a: 2 b: orange  c: 100
a: 3 b: cherry  c: 100

a: 0 b: apple   c: 200
a: 1 b: pear    c: 200
a: 2 b: orange  c: 200
a: 3 b: cherry  c: 200

a: 0 b: apple   c: 300
a: 1 b: pear    c: 300
a: 2 b: orange  c: 300
a: 3 b: cherry  c: 300
```

but what I want is output.

```
a: 0 b: apple   c: 100
a: 1 b: pear    c: 200
a: 2 b: orange  c: 300
a: 3 b: cherry  c: 400
```

Comment: can you show us what's in `$first` and `$second`? that will be easier to help you

Comment: @Kaddath, I updated the subject.

Comment: @H.Marcus Why do you expect 400 , if  it is not in output now?

Comment: Your mock declaration of the arrays is weird. Can you give a couple of actual lines from your code?

Comment: @splash58,  I gave an example.İt is progressing regularly.

Comment: Woudln't say that the output for for each is faulty, you're using it in a wrong way. If you want four outputs, you better write only one for each and manually increase the indexers for the other arrays since you obviously don't want a second for each.

Comment: Actually, I don't think there's *any* way that such code gives such output. `$first1[0]` is a constant in each of the inner `foreach` loops, it can't change values like that. You probably want to redo all your mock code if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops,because now you get all combinations of values of both arrays

```
foreach ($first as $k=>$first1) {
   echo "a: ".$k." b: ".$first1[0]." c: ".$second[$k][0]."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. Where did I make a mistake?Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Two loops combine each value from the 1st array with each value form thq 2nd. But you want to get only corresponding ones

Comment: Yes I now understand the logic better.Thank you.